# Audio transformation with STFT and Cent-scaling

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm trying to implement the approach for processing audio like it is done in this paper: [Block-Level Audio Features for Music Genre Classification](http://www.cp.jku.at/people/schedl/Research/Publications/pdf/ss_gc_mirex_2009.pdf)

Can someone explain me how the part marked in yellow works?
I'm **new to signal processing** and I already gathered information on what a frequency bin(intervals between frequency samples) is.
I also have some basic understandment on how a Cent-scale works:[image]

1. What do they mean with "summing all frequency bins"?
2. How do they come up with 97 Dimensions?
3. Is there any easy approach on how to implement their procedure? Preferably in Python

Here is a screenshot about what I'm trying to do:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do they mean with "summing all frequency bins"?

The magnitude spectrogram can be thought of as a matrix where each column holds the FFT magnitude samples of each consecutive frame. The authors perform STFT on frames of length $N = 2048$, so each column will hold $1025$ values representing the magnitude of each (positive) frequency component present in that frame. You can map these $1025$ bins (i.e. rows) to frequency in $\texttt{Hz}$ as such:
$$f_k(\texttt{Hz}) = k \cdot \frac{f_s}{N}$$

> $k = 0 \cdots 1024$

Conversely:
$$ k = f_k(\texttt{Hz}) \cdot \frac{N}{f_s}$$

*For example each column at bin number $10$ (= row number $10$) will hold the values representing the magnitude of the signal's component of frequency $10 \cdot 22000/2048 = 107.4 \texttt{Hz}$ for each frame (that statement is not entirely accurate but for sake of brevity let’s leave it at that)*.

*"Sum frequency bins"* $k = 23 \rightarrow 27$ (for example) means "summing rows $k = 23 \rightarrow 27$". Or, in other words, "for each column (= each successive frame), we're going to sum the values found in rows $23 \rightarrow 27$".

---

> How do they come up with 97 Dimensions?

- The sampling frequency is $f_s = 22000 \,\texttt{Hz}$, so we're
  interested in frequencies from $\texttt{DC} \rightarrow 11000
     \,\texttt{Hz}$
- In cent-scale, $11000
     \,\texttt{Hz}$ corresponds to $\approx 11273 \,\texttt{cents}$
- The authors sum frequency bins starting at $2050 \,\texttt{cents}$, with $100 \,\texttt{cents}$ increments. Note $2050 \,\texttt{cents}$ corresponds to $53.43 \,\texttt{Hz}$
- That means the output will have $\lfloor \frac{11273 - 2050}{100} \rfloor = 92$ cent-bins.
- Add to that the original spectrogram bins corresponding to frequencies $0 \rightarrow 53.43 \,\texttt{Hz}$, which are bins $1 \rightarrow 5$
- That gives you a total of $97$ bins.

---

You should try emailing the authors, there's a chance they can send you their code! However, here is some Matlab code that can help. It gives you the cent-scaled spectrogram provided an audio signal. A python implementation would be easy to write based on that.

```
% x = audio signal sampled at fs = 22000 Hz

% Perform STFT
window_size = 2048;
hop_size = 512;
s = spectrogram(x, window_size, window_size-hop_size, window_size, fs);

% Compute magnitude spectrum
magnitude_spectrum = abs(s);

% Define Cent-scale parameters
cent_start = 2050;
cent_bandwidth = 100;

% Compute Cent-scale
num_cent_bins = floor( (hz2cent(fs/2) - cent_start) / cent_bandwidth );
num_total_bins = num_cent_bins + 5;
num_frames = floor( (length(x) - window_size) / hop_size ) + 1;
cent_spectrogram = zeros(num_total_bins, num_frames);

% fill the first 5 bins with the spectrogram
cent_spectrogram(1:5, :) = magnitude_spectrum(1:5, :);
for i = 1:num_cent_bins
    
    frequency_hz = cent2hz(cent_start + (i-1)*cent_bandwidth);
    frequency_bin_start = round(frequency_hz * (window_size / fs)) + 1;

    frequency_hz = cent2hz(cent_start + i*cent_bandwidth);
    frequency_bin_end = round(frequency_hz * (window_size / fs)) + 1;
    
    cent_spectrogram(i+5,:) = sum(magnitude_spectrum(frequency_bin_start:frequency_bin_end,:), 1);
    
end

% Function to convert cent to frequency in Hz
function frequency_hz = cent2hz(cent)
    frequency_hz = 440*2^(-5700/1200)*2^(cent ./ 1200);
end

% Function to convert frequency in Hz to cent
function cent = hz2cent(frequency_hz)  
    cent = 1200 * log2(frequency_hz ./ (440 * 2^(-5700/1200)));
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
• About 'sum frequency': So in row 10 of each column there is the sum of 1...10?

• DC -> 11 kHz why is it cut in half? Is it because of the Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem?

• How do I get the five original spectogram bins (0 -> 53.43 Hz)

Comment: One more question: For the declaration of num_frames you used length(y). There is no y in your code and also when using length(x) num_frames gets negative. What did you mean there?

Comment: Yes, because of Nyquist-Shannon. Please look and study the code I provided. It has clear answer to your other two questions

Comment: Yes, should be x, not y. I’ve edited!

Comment: To be a little clearer for you. The first 5 bins come from the original spectrogram. And the way we sum rows is in the “for”loop.

Comment: num_frames = floor( (length(x) - window_size) / hop_size ) + 1;
with length(x) = 1025, window_size = 2048 and hop_size = 512 equals to -1. Is this what you intended?

Comment: Length(x) = 1025 doesn’t make any sense, that would mean your input audio signal is 46ms long… at this point I have to say, you probably need to grind your teeth on **much** easier problems before tackling something like this. I’m not being coy, I’m sure you’ll learn fast! But this is pretty advanced stuff and I personally think you’re doing yourself a disservice by trying to implement such things without a base understanding of audio processing. In any case, please hit the accept button so others can benefit!

Comment: I used the librosa function .stft() and it returns a matrix of len 1025.
..Then I'll probably have to use a different function for the transformation..
Like I mentioned I'm pretty new to the whole topic.
I'll definitely accept your answer and I'm super grateful for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145446/discussion-between-jdip-and-rocket).